# how to put bird counts data in d3.js to draw bar-chart on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js, svg

I am new to d3.js ,I made reference this example: http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/4531633 .

I changed the example's map to Google map  ,and want to use SVG to draw bar
chart on the Google map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
.gmap{ display: block; width: 1000px; height: 800px; }
.stations, .stations svg { position: absolute; }

.stations svg { width: 120px; height: 30px; padding-right: 100px; font: 12px sans-serif; }

.stations circle { fill: yellow; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
</style>
<body>
<div class="gmap" id="map-canvas"></div>  
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script></script>

<script>
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = { zoom: 8, center: new                  
   google.maps.LatLng(23.7147979,120.7105502) };
   map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map-canvas') , mapOptions);
}

initialize();

var width = 960, height = 960;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);


d3.csv("223-loc.csv", function(data) {
    var parse = d3.time.format("%Y/%m/%d").parse; 

    aaa = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d){ return d.birdName;})
            .entries(stocks = data);        
    aaa_copy = d3.nest()
             .key(function(d){ return d.birdName;})
             .entries(stocks = data);
    var position2keep= new Array(); 
    var i=0;
    aaa.forEach(function(s) 
    {
        for (nn=0; nn<selectAryy.length; nn++)
        {
            if (s.key == selectAryy[nn])
            {   position2keep.push(i); break; } 
        }
    i++;
    });

    position2keep.sort(); 
    for (j=aaa_copy.length-1; j>=0; j--) 
{ 
    if ( position2keep.indexOf(j) == -1) 
        aaa_copy.splice(j,1); 
}

aaa_copy.forEach(function(s) {
    s.values.forEach(function(d) { 
        for (nn=0; nn<selectAryy.length; nn++){
            if (d.birdName== selectAryy[nn]){   
                d.date = parse(d.date);
                d.count = +d.count;
                d.lat = +d.lat;
                d.lng = +d.lng; 
            } 
        }

   bars = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(s)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "bars")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate("+ d.lat +","+   
   d.lng+")";});

    bars.append("rect")               
      .attr('height',  function(d) {return d.count*1000})
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('y', function(d) {return -(d.count)})
      .attr("class", "bars")
      .style("fill", "green");

   bars.append("text")
  .text(function(d) {return d.location})
  .attr("x", -10)
  .attr("y", 18);

    bars.setMap(map);   
    }); 
   });  
 });
</script>
</body>
```

My CSV data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SUWnrBmDwSWkI4bVNtOTNSOTA

I use d3.csv load data,it works.
But When I want to put the data into SVG to draw bar chart,it didn't work.

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: How does it 'not work'?

Comment: The Google map can be shown normally,but the bar-chart can not be draw on the map .

Comment: It just doesn't appear?  Or does something else happen?  Are there any javascript errors?  Is it there in the DOM?  Have you tried to step through the javascript in a debugger and figure out what is happening?

Comment: console.log doesn't have any error. The data is put in Array aaa and aaa_copy,but SVG doesn't draw it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided example there are some issues:

- `selectAryy` is not defined
- and most importantly  `bars.setMap(map);` does not seem valid. Do you mean  `setMap` function of `google.maps.OverlayView` object?

In order to create a bar chart on Google Maps i would recommend to implement it as  [Custom Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple).

Having said that the below example demonstrates how to add `svg` objects (bar chart) into Google Maps using *overlay* technique:

**Example**

```js
function BarChartOverlay(chartData, map){
    this.map_ = map;
    this.chartData_ = chartData;
    this.div_=null;
    this.setMap(map);
}

BarChartOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

BarChartOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function(){
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id','chartDiv');

    var chartArea = d3.select(div).append("svg");
                 
    this.chartData_.forEach(function(item){

       var pos = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(new google.maps.LatLng(item[0], item[1]));

       var bar = chartArea
                  .append("rect")
                  .attr("x", pos.x)
                  .attr("y", pos.y)
                  .attr("width", 40)
                  .attr("height", item[2])
                  .attr("fill-opacity", '0.5')
                  .attr("fill", 'purple');
    });
    
     
    this.div_ = div;
    this.chartArea_ = chartArea;
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);    
    
};

BarChartOverlay.prototype.draw = function(){
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.map_.getBounds().getSouthWest());
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.map_.getBounds().getNorthEast());
    var chartAreaSize = sw.x + ' ' +  ne.y + ' ' + (ne.x - sw.x) + ' ' + (sw.y - ne.y);
    this.chartArea_.attr('viewBox',chartAreaSize);
};

BarChartOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function(){
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
};



function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8, center: new
                 google.maps.LatLng(23.7147979, 120.7105502)
            };
            var chartData = [
              [25.204757,121.6896172,100],
              [22.7972447,121.0713702,130],
              [24.254972,120.6011066,80]
            ];
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            var overlay = new BarChartOverlay(chartData, map);
}
initialize();
```

```css
.gmap {
   display: block;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="gmap" id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Gremyachev   Thank you. It can be work now. But have another problem is the bar-chart can't positioned with the map zoom in or zoom out . Can you provide example for me or can you help me again?